# Working with same sockets from different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have created and connected socket in one thread. Can I use the same `Socket` object in another thread?

Them same question is about `OutputStream`. Can I use it differn threads.

```
Socket s = null;
//create and connect cocket
//...
OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
```

For example, can I write data from different threads?

```
out.write(byteArr);
```

Comment: Of course, you can use a variable in class whitch extends Thread.

Comment: Sure you can, but you will create an unholy mess of spaghetti data that you will never unravel at the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use a variable in class whitch extends Thread. For Example:

```
public class MyClass extends Thread {
    Socket s;
    public MyClass(Socket s){
        ...
        this.s = s;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ... your code and usage of socket
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
        out.write(byteArr);
    }
}
```

In a main class or where you want

```
Myclass m = New MyClass(mySocket);
m.start();
```